# c++ compiler free to choose between user defined and compiler generated copy-constructors?

Tags: c++, mingw, gnu, copy-constructor

I have the following sample code (a stripped down version of my programme)

Class 'some_class' has a constructor with default parameters. The compiler is able to recognise this constructor as a copy constructor. In the main function, this constructor is called when I order for a copy constructed object called 'b'. But when I construct 'c' from a function result, the compiler calls a compiler generated copy constructor (which copies the bit pattern). I can tell by the value of c.some_data, which should have been set by my own copy constructor to a value of 2.

1) What does the standard say about this?
2) Is my compiler broken?

I use MinGW with no options but a specification of my source file name and a name for the executable. I got my port of the gnu open source compiler from the official MinGW website, I'm using the latest version. Have I found a bug, or is this due to my (mis)understanding of c++?

Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class some_class
{
public:
    some_class(int p = 0) :
        some_data(p)
    {
        std::cout << "user defined constructor (p = " << p << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    some_class(const some_class &, int = 0)
    {
        std::cout << "user defined copy constructor" << std::endl;

        some_data = 2;
    }

    int some_data;
};

extern some_class some_function_returning_some_class_object();

int main(int, char **)
{
        std::cout << "creating a, with no parameters" << std::endl;
    some_class a;
        std::cout << "creating b, a copy of a" << std::endl;
    some_class b = a;
        std::cout << "creating c, copy constructed from a function result" << std::endl;
    some_class c = some_function_returning_some_class_object();
        std::cout << "c.some_data = " << c.some_data << std::endl;
}

some_class some_function_returning_some_class_object()
{
    some_class a(1);

    return a;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
creating a, with no parameters
user defined constructor (p = 0)
creating b, a copy of a
user defined copy constructor
creating c, copy constructed from a function result
user defined constructor (p = 1)
c.some_data = 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is not using the compiler-defined default copy constructor. It is presumably using [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to skip the copy altogether.

Comment: +1. Could you show how to override the rvalue reference constructor, to get some debugging output?

Comment: Then it should call my own copy constructor, note that the compiler wil not inline my function and does not know the inner when it is called from main!

Comment: @bert-jan: inlining is not required for the return value optimization to work, all that's needed is that the caller provides the address of the return value (e.g. on the caller's stack) as part of the calling convention for functions that return class types by value. If you can, try printing out in `some_function_returning_some_class_object` the address of the object it's about to return, and then in `main` the address of `c`. If they're the same then you have copy elision.

Comment: I shall try if it works when I can rule out the return value optimizing stuff by doing something with the object in the function before returning it!

Comment: @user946850: You mean the move constructor? bert-jan doesn't have one, and the compiler won't generate a move constructor if you have a user-defined copy constructor. If RVO is going on, the move constructor won't be invoked even if it's defined anyway.

Comment: @bert-jan: Doing something with the object doesn't mean it hasn't already been constructed in the space allocated in the caller's stack. Printing out the address as Steve suggests is probably the only thing that will work.

Comment: @bert-jan: it depends what kind of thing you do. The best way to obstruct RVO is to create *two* objects in `some_function_returning_some_class_object` in different automatic variables, then toss a coin to decide which one to return. Since the compiler doesn't know which variable is the return object, it can't construct either one of them directly into the return value. To be safe, I'd print something after creating the objects but before tossing the coin, just to be absolutely sure the compiler can't re-order the object creation after the coin toss.

Comment: @user946850, why is this RVO if I have both a copy constructor and a default constructor (It may not skip those two constructors all together, it is unwanted control flow changing).

Comment: @bert-jan: Yes it can. RVO is specifically allowed to change the observable behavior of the program. This is in the first paragraph of the linked wikipedia page.

Comment: I tried by ruling out RVO and now MinGW has inserted code to call MY copy constructor (all works fine). I still find this RVO scarry when it bypasses my contructor causing to change the control flow in a way that could change (invalidate) the entire programme. I shall read what wiki says about this.

Comment: Oops, I just remembered, `gcc` has an option to disable copy elision, `-fno-elide-constructors`, then you should see two copies during construction of `c`. So there's no need to outwit the optimizer like we described above. Copy elision can invalidate the program if you do something in your copy ctor *other than* what is necessary to account for the fact that an object has been copied. So, Don't Do That Then. You shouldn't rely on copy construction in the cases where it can be elided, any more than you would rely on the order of evaluation of function arguments, since both are unspecified.

Comment: @bert-jan I personnaly think your copy-constructor is way more scary than RVO... why would you call it a copy-constructor if the returned object is not identical to the original one ?

Comment: @undo, It doesn't matter if the copied object is binary different in it's bit pattern, it could still logically be the same. And, regardless of it not being the same, I could rely on side-effects of my copy constructor. And if a copy constructor was - in your opinion - not allowed to create a copy that is not identical, why not modify the standard of c++ and use memcpy() function to make a binary equal copy. These considerations are among the ones I could think of to explain why a copy constructed obejct is not always the same as the original.